# How to keep shiny app running its code after exiting it?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app which will send mass email to the clients after it approaches 24-hr deadline to purchase the product, so that clients who were unaware of the product can have time to purchase it. Here is the part of the code from server.R. This code checks the time difference between current time (using now() function from lubridate library) and the end_time (which is in the database) to see if it is 24 hours or less. If so, it should send email to the clients. It doesn't seem like program does that when it is closed. It seems like it checks for the time difference and send email only when program is on and accessed by somebody. Should I make now() reactive? Would that make program do the job when it is ran by absolutely nobody? I made 'recent_email' reactive in a hope that ti will do the job but it didn't.

```
recent_email <- reactive({

    # Connects to database

    invalidateLater(90000,session)

    con <- dbConnect(drv = MySQL(),user="username",password="password",dbname="my_db",host="my_server_name")

    # Loads FA_TABLE from mysql

    tbl <- dbReadTable(con,"FA_TABLE",row.names=NULL)

    # Subsets the tbl by desired columns and saves it to tbl7

    tbl7 <- tbl[,c("Player","Bid_Num","Start_Time","End_Time","Points")]

    # Get a list of all FA names

    name_list <- unique(tbl7$Player)

    # Vector that keeps the row of FA with highest bid_number

    retain_row <- vector()

    # For loop that will assign the row to retain to the vector called 'retain_row'

    for(k in 1:length(name_list))
    {
      max_bid <- max(tbl7$Bid_Num[tbl7$Player %in% name_list[k]],na.rm = TRUE)

      retain_row[k] <- which((tbl7$Bid_Num == max_bid) & (tbl7$Player == name_list[k]))
    }

    # Subsets the tbl7 by row number saved on "retain_row"

    tbl7 <- tbl7[retain_row,]

    # Create column called "Time_Left"

    tbl7$Time_Left <- ""

    # If Bid_Num is more than 1, add time left. If Bid_Num is not more than 1, Then add "NA"

    for(l in 1:nrow(tbl7))
    {
      ifelse(tbl7$Bid_Num[l] > 1, tbl7$Time_Left[l] <- round(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(tbl7$End_Time[l]),units="sec") - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(now(tzone="EST")),units="sec"),digits=0) + 18000,tbl7$Time_Left[l] <- "NA")
    }

    # Remove row with NA value in Time Left column

    tbl7 <- tbl7[!tbl7$Time_Left %in% c(NA,"NA"),]

    tbl7$Time_Left <- as.numeric(tbl7$Time_Left)

    # Read "clock" table from mysql server

    clock <- dbReadTable(con,"clock",row.names=NULL)

    clock$send <- as.character(clock$send)

    # 24hr, 12hr, 1hr, and 0hr convert to seconds

    t24 <- 3600 * 24 # 86400
    t12 <- 3600 * 12 # 43200
    t1 <- 3600 # 3600
    t0 <- 0 # 0

    # Checks the clock24, clock12, and clock1 variable. Clock shows "YES" when email already has been
    # sent out at the hours specified. (e.g. 24, 12, or 1 hr). "NO" when email has not been sent out.
    # Here is what this loop does:
    # 1) If email has been sent out at the hours specified (So "YES" is given) but 'time remaining' 
    # for specific player from tbl7 is greater than the hours (24,12 or 1), then reset the clock24,
    # clock12, and clock1 of specific player to "yes" from "no", making player eligible for mass email again.
    # 2) If email has not been sent out at the hours specified (So "NO" is given) but 'time remaining'
    # for specific player from tbl7 is less than the hours (24: less than 24 but more than 12, 
    #12: less than 12 but more than 1, or 1: less than 1 but has not been timed out), then send out a
    # mass email about the player.

    for(m in 1:nrow(clock))
    {
      clock <- dbReadTable(con,"clock",row.names=NULL)

      if(length(which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])) > 0)
      {
        # If time left for particular player is more than 24 hours and labeled "YES", that means 
        # email has been sent out before, but bidding increased time left, making it eligible for email
        # alert again. So switch label to "NO"

        # Run this if time left of particular is more than 24 hours
        if(((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) >= t24) == TRUE)
        {
          # "NO" assigned if email was already sent out before and it has more than 24 hours left.
          # "YES" assigned if email was not sent out before and it has more than 24 
          ifelse((clock$clock24[m] == "YES") == TRUE,clock$clock24[m] <- "NO",clock$clock24[m] <- "NO")

          clock$clock12[m] <- "NO"
          clock$clock1[m] <- "NO"

        }

        # Run this if time left of particular player between 12 and 24
        if((((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) < t24) == TRUE) & (((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) >= t12) == TRUE))
        {
          # If email has been sent out 24hr and time remaining is between 12 and 24, keep it "YES". If not email hasn't been sent, keep it "NO" so you can send email.
          ifelse((clock$clock24[m] == "YES") == TRUE, clock$clock24[m] <- "YES", clock$clock24[m] <- "NO")

          # Email has not been sent out, write "24" into "send" form. This is a way to signal the system
          # to send 24-hour warning email.
          if(clock$clock24[m] == "NO")
          {
            clock$send[m] <- 24
            clock$clock24[m] <- "YES"
          }
        }


        ###

        if(((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) >= t12) == TRUE)
        {
          # "NO" assigned if email was already sent out before and it has more than 12 hours left.
          # "YES" assigned if email was not sent out before and it has more than 12
          ifelse((clock$clock12[m] == "YES") == TRUE,clock$clock12[m] <- "NO",clock$clock12[m] <- "NO")

          clock$clock1[m] <- "NO" 
        }

        # Run this if time left of particular between 12 and 24
        if((((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) < t12) == TRUE) & (((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) >= t1) == TRUE))
        {
          # 
          ifelse((clock$clock12[m] == "YES") == TRUE, clock$clock12[m] <- "YES", clock$clock12[m] <- "NO")

          if(clock$clock12[m] == "NO")
          {
            clock$send[m] <- 12
            clock$clock12[m] <- "YES"

          }
        }

        ###

        if(((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) >= t1) == TRUE)
        {
          # "NO" assigned if email was already sent out before and it has more than 1 hour left.
          # "YES" assigned if email was not sent out before and it has more than 1
          ifelse((clock$clock1[m] == "YES") == TRUE,clock$clock1[m] <- "NO",clock$clock1[m] <- "NO")

        }

        # Run this if time left of particular between 0 and 1
        if((((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) < t1) == TRUE) & (((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) > 0) == TRUE))
        {
          # 
          ifelse((clock$clock1[m] == "YES") == TRUE, clock$clock1[m] <- "YES", clock$clock1[m] <- "NO")

          if(clock$clock1[m] == "NO")
          {
            clock$send[m] <- 1
            clock$clock1[m] <- "YES"

          }
        }

        # Insert code for 0hr email

        if(((tbl7$Time_Left[which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])]) == 0) == TRUE)
        {
          # "NO" assigned if email was already sent out before and it has more than 1 hour left.
          # "YES" assigned if email was not sent out before and it has more than 1
          ifelse((clock$clockend[m] == "YES") == TRUE,clock$clockend[m] <- "YES",clock$clockend[m] <- "YES")
          clock$clockend[m] <- "YES"
          clock$send[m] <- 0

        }

      }

      if(length(which(tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[m])) == 0)
      {
        next;
      }
      clock <- clock[,c("Player","clock24","clock12","clock1","clockend","send")]

      dbWriteTable(con,"clock",clock,overwrite=TRUE)

    }

    mail_out <- which(clock$send %in% c("0","1","12","24"))

    if(length(mail_out) > 0)
    {
      for(d in 1:length(mail_out))
      {
        which_hour <- clock$send[mail_out[d]]

        if(which_hour %in% c("1","12","24"))
        {
          updateStatus(paste0(which_hour,"-hour alert for ",unlist(strsplit(as.character(clock$Player[mail_out[d]])," "))[2]," ",sub(",","",unlist(strsplit(as.character(clock$Player[mail_out[d]])," "))[1]),". Make your bid by ", tbl7$End_Time[tbl7$Player %in% clock$Player[mail_out[d]]],"ET"))

        }

        if(which_hour %in% c("0",0))
        {
          tbl_highest <- tbl[tbl$Player == clock$Player[mail_out[d]],]

          tbl_highest <- tbl_highest[order(tbl_highest$Points,decreasing = TRUE),]

          tbl_highest <- tbl_highest[1,]

          updateStatus(paste0("Going once, going twice, and..SOLD! ",unlist(strsplit(as.character(clock$Player[mail_out[d]])," "))[2]," ",sub(",","",unlist(strsplit(as.character(clock$Player[mail_out[d]])," "))[1])," signs with ",tbl_highest$Club[1]," for ",tbl_highest$summary[1],"ET"))

        }
        clock$send[mail_out[d]] <- NA

      }
    }

    clock <- clock[,c("Player","clock24","clock12","clock1","clockend","send")]

    dbWriteTable(con,"clock",clock,overwrite=TRUE)

    dbDisconnect(con)

    tbl8 <- tbl[(nrow(tbl)):(nrow(tbl)-9),]

    tbl8 <- tbl8[,c("row_names","Player","Year_Guaranteed","summary","End_Time")]

    tbl8$row_names <- c(1:10)

    tbl8

  })
```

Comment: If you're using shiny server I would definitely check the sever settings for how long the process runs until idle.

Comment: 8 hours max. so if i keep it from being idle, it will be okay?

Comment: Run a hour test to check

Comment: Thanks. Keeping the app on seems to do the trick